# Кавычки при символах

Tags: грамотная-речь, кавычки, оформление-текста

*Для этого вам нужно в правом верхнем углу нажать на кнопку ∙∙∙ и написать нам сообщение*.

*В конце названия бренда часто ставится знак ™.*

*Каждое издание по-своему отбивает знак % от предшествующей цифры.*

Известно, что в кавычки заключаются слова и выражения, если они  употреблены в метаязыковой функции, т.е. для указания именно на это слово или выражение, а не на обозначаемый им предмет или понятие. Также в этом случае вместо кавычек широко применяется курсив. Однако что насчёт символов? Нужно ли их заключать в кавычки либо выделять курсивом, или следует считать, что они обозначают видовые понятия, а слово перед ними — родовое понятие, и выделять их нет необходимости?

Comment: Только не кавычки. Строго доказать не могу, поэтому даю как комментарий.

Answer (score 2):

> В конце названия бренда часто ставится знак **™**.

Не указывая бренд, значок нехорошо отрывать от строки: знак ТМ, знак **ТМ**. Хорошо бы развернуть — ТМ (trade mark) или ТМ (торговая марка), т. к. есть различия.

> Каждое издание по-своему отбивает знак ***%*** от предшествующей цифры.

Можно знак ***%*** выделять жирным, хотя у многих гарнитур Bold визуально не работает.